# PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

On my website I allow people to upload image galleries. When they click an image there is a **next** and **previous** button at the bottom so they can easily scroll back and forth through the images.

I am getting the below error in my log located at /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/var/log/php-fpm/

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in . . . on line 12
```

It is talking about the line below in my code:

```
$max = count($photos);
```

Below is the other code that comes with that line:

```
$photos = get_field('gallery');
$max = count($photos);    <------- error line here -------->
$current = (isset($_GET['image'])) ? intval($_GET['image']) : false;
if ($current !== false) {
    if ($current > $max) $current = $max;
    if ($current < 1) $current = 1;
}

$next = (($current + 1) < $max) ? ($current + 1) : $max;
$prev = (($current - 1) > 1) ? ($current - 1) : 1;
?>
```

Basically this code uses **get_field('gallery')** to get the total amount of photos in the gallery and the number is assigned to variable **max**.

The rest of the code is how the **next** and **previous** buttons work.

I do not know what is wrong. Can somebody help with this?

Comment: What does get_field() do?

Comment: Hmmm let me see. It is part of the Wordpress theme files I am using so I don't quite know. Let me find out

Comment: Please do some basic debugging. Add a `var_dump($photos);` before your `count($photos);` to see what the variable actually contains. It's obviously not of any countable type. Also, `get_field()` is most commonly used with the plugin "Advanced Custom Fields".

Comment: Yes I see now. I have ACF installed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general, solution is simple:

First debbug with `var_dump()` what `$photos` return. Than you will know what's the issue.

`count()` accept array and if you have `false`, `null` or anything else you will have error.

Just do something like this:

```
$photos = get_field('gallery');
if(!is_array($photos) || empty($photos)) $photos = array(); // FIX ERROR!!!
$max = count($photos);    <------- error line here -------->
$current = (isset($_GET['image']) && !empty($_GET['image']) && is_numeric($_GET['image'])) ? intval($_GET['image']) : 0;
if ($current > 0) {
    if ($current > $max) $current = $max;
    if ($current < 1) $current = 1;
}

$next = (($current + 1) < $max) ? ($current + 1) : $max;
$prev = (($current - 1) > 1) ? ($current - 1) : 1;
?>
```

With `if(!is_array($photos) || empty($photos)) $photos = array();` before `$max = count($photos);` you fixing your issue and anything what is not array or empty (0, NULL, FALSE, '') will be fixed and you will have in the count `$max` result `0` because array is empty.

---

### **IMPORTANT!!!**

**You should not work like this.** You need to know what information you receive and expect in variables. The code must remain clean and correcting such errors is a bad practice. If you receive an array, then the array is expected and you must have checks before any calculating.

---

### UPDATE:

Also you have error in

```
$current = (isset($_GET['image'])) ? intval($_GET['image']) : false;
if ($current !== false)
```

I fix it to work like this:

```
$current = (isset($_GET['image']) && !empty($_GET['image']) && is_numeric($_GET['image'])) ? intval($_GET['image']) : 0;
if ($current > 0)
```

Reason for that is that you have calculations below and you not expect `(false + 1)` to be something good. `false` can be translated to `0` but in your case you can also get error. For that case I replace `false` with `0`, add `empty()` and `is_numeric()` check and you have no errors there.

Comment: I will use this and see how it goes. Thank you!!